# Change color when editing input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change backgroundColor based on a input value, however it does not seem to work, when i change the color from the colorpicker even though i can see the input value change?

http://jsfiddle.net/AHZBT/4/

**Java Code**

```
$(function() {
    var bgColor = $('#colorpickerField1').val();   
    $('body').css("backgroundColor",'#' + bgColor);

    $('#colorpickerField1').keyup(function() {
       $('body').css("backgroundColor",'#' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: You are listening to keyup, so the backgound color is going to change only if you type something.

Comment: Working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to change the background in real-time, I pulled this from the documenation:

```
<input class="color {onImmediateChange:'updateInfo(this);'}" id="colorpickerField1" value="66ff00">

function updateInfo(color) {
    $('body').css("backgroundColor",'#' + color);
}
```

http://jscolor.com/try.php#onimmediatechange

Answer (score 4):

Use change event:

```
    $('#colorpickerField1').change(function() {
       $('body').css("backgroundColor",'#' + $(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked ok with blur:

```
$(function() {
    var bgColor = $('#colorpickerField1').val();   
    $('body').css("backgroundColor",'#' + bgColor);

    $('#colorpickerField1').blur(function() {
       $('body').css("backgroundColor",'#' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```